# Compare 2 lists in file and save result in another file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have 2 lists recorded in files (File1.txt and File2.txt) and I need to compare line by line and record the amount of equal occurrences in the Output.txt file.

However, the result written to the output is incorrect. See below the code I used and the result obtained and the desired:

```
input_file1 = open('C:\\Temp\\File1.txt', 'r')
input_file2 = open('C:\\Temp\\File2.txt', 'r')
output_file = open('C:\\Temp\\Output.txt','w')

match = 0
strOutput = ""

for line1 in input_file1:
    LST1 = list(line1)
    input_file2.seek(0)
    output_file.write('\n')
    for line2 in input_file2:
        LST2 = list(line2)
        match = len(set(LST1).intersection(set(LST2)))
        strOutput = str(match) + ','  + line2
        output_file.write("%s" %(strOutput))
                        
output_file.close()
input_file2.close()
input_file1.close()
```

**input_file1:**
01,04,07,23,39
03,05,08,37,45
02,03,10,13,28

**input_file2:**
01,02,03,21,22,23,27
03,05,10,13,37,39,47

**output (INCORRECT!):**
7,01,02,03,21,22,23,27
7,03,05,10,13,37,39,47
5,01,02,03,21,22,23,27
6,03,05,10,13,37,39,47
5,01,02,03,21,22,23,27
4,03,05,10,13,37,39,47

**output (CORRECT):**
2,01,02,03,21,22,23,27
1,03,05,10,13,37,39,47
1,01,02,03,21,22,23,27
3,03,05,10,13,37,39,47
2,01,02,03,21,22,23,27
3,03,05,10,13,37,39,47

**OR:**

**output (CORRECT):**
2,1,2,3,21,22,23,27
1,3,5,10,13,37,39,47
1,1,2,3,21,22,23,27
3,3,5,10,13,37,39,47
2,1,2,3,21,22,23,27
3,3,5,10,13,37,39,47

Comment: Are you trying to split the items into a list as in [01 , 02 , 03, ...]? Because in your current code it seems like it is generating a list as in: [ '0' , '1' , ',' , '0' , ....] That might be the problem.

Comment: @zaid-al-shattle - Really, this is one of the problems. But if you use 1,2,3 (coverts for integers),... in the input files (File1.txt and File2.txt) it doesn't give the desired output either.

Comment: give me a few minutes and I can try to troubleshoot it for you.

Comment: @J.Silva You need to *parse* the input lines, like this: `LST1 = line1.strip().split(',')` or `LST1 = list(map(int, line1.strip().split(',')))`.

Comment: @ekhumoro - Congratulations.Thanks for the code. I also liked the solution of zaid-al-shattle. Both worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed code:

```
input_file1 = open('File1.txt', 'r')
input_file2 = open('File2.txt', 'r')
output_file = open('Output.txt','w')

match = 0
strOutput = ""

for line1 in input_file1:
    LST1 = line1.strip().split(',')
    input_file2.seek(0)
    output_file.write('\n')
    for line2 in input_file2:
        LST2 = line2.strip().split(',')
        match = len(set(LST1).intersection(set(LST2)))
        strOutput = str(match) + ','  + line2
        output_file.write("%s" %(strOutput))
                        
output_file.close()
input_file2.close()
input_file1.close()
```

There are two main issues:

1- The original line: `LST1 = list(line1)` wasn't generating the correct list, ending with a list of: `['0' , '1' , ',' , '0' , ....]` instead of `['01','02',...]`

2- In your originaly document, you have a new line character at the end of every line, thus your line1 looks like this: `'01,04,07,23,39\n'`
To solve this, we remove the last 2 character.

With both of those changes, you end up with this line:

```
LST1 = line1.strip().split(',')
```

Where `.strip()` removes the new line character, and `.split(',')` splits it correctly.

Running that code gave me this output:

```
2,01,02,03,21,22,23,27
1,03,05,10,13,37,39,47
1,01,02,03,21,22,23,27
3,03,05,10,13,37,39,47
2,01,02,03,21,22,23,27
3,03,05,10,13,37,39,47
```

Comment: Your first solution is error-prone, because it assumes every line must end with a newline. It's more robust to use `strip()` to remove any trailing whitespace.

Comment: I have noticed that, hence my edit. Do you suggest removing the first option all-together and replacing it with the edited answer? @ekhumoro?

Comment: @zaid-al-shattle - Congratulations.Thanks for the explanation. I also liked the solution of ekhumoro. Both worked.

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle I think so, because it can give the wrong output. (Also, it is actually removing *one* character, not two).

Comment: Noted, will edit it now. I have made a mistake in writing two characters (Since /n is considered one character). Thank you for your feedback!